# How to show paginationa in jqgrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, jqgrid

I am trying to show pagination of the jq grid. But it is not working. It is not showing any data in the grid. I am new in jqgrid and i have tried, here is my example.

My action in controller

```
 public ActionResult itemList(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows)
        {
            int pageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(page) - 1;
            int pageSize = rows;
            int totalRecords = db.tbl_Item.Count();
            int totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRecords / (float)pageSize);


            var v = new
            {

                total = totalPages,
                page,
                records = totalRecords,
                rows = (
                         from t in db.tbl_Item
                         select new
                         {
                             i = t.id,
                             cell = new string[]{
                                                t.batchno,t.brand,t.buyingPrice.ToString(),
                                                t.catg,
                                                t.itemcode,
                                                t.name,
                                                t.qtyLimit.ToString(),
                                                t.Quantity.ToString(),
                                                t.sellingPrice.ToString(),t.supplier,t.unitType,t.vat.ToString()
                                     }
                         }).ToArray()
            };       
            return Json(v, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

And the javascript code are

```
jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
                cache: false,
                async: false,
                url: '/Settings/itemList/',
                datatype: 'json',
                mtype: 'GET',


                colNames: ['id','New Item', 'Batch No', 'Supplier', 'Unit', 'B. Price', 'S. Price','Item Code','Vat','Limit'],
                colModel: [
                    { name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 110, align: 'center',hidden:true },
                                 { name: 'name', index: 'name', width: 110, align: 'center' },
                                 { name: 'batchno', index: 'batchno', width: 110, align: 'center' },
                                 { name: 'supplier', index: 'supplier', width: 110, align: 'center' },
                                 { name: 'unitType', index: 'unitType', width: 110, align: 'center', editoptions: { readonly: 'readonly' } },
                                 { name: 'buyingPrice', index: 'buyingPrice', width: 110, align: 'center', editoptions: { readonly: 'readonly' } },
                                 { name: 'sellingPrice', index: 'sellingPrice', align: 'center' },
                                 { name: 'itemcode', index: 'itemcode', width: 110, align: 'center'},
                                 { name: 'vat', index: 'vat', width: 110, align: 'center', editoptions: { readonly: 'readonly' } },
                                 { name: 'qtyLimit', index: 'qtyLimit', align: 'center' }

                ],

                pager: jQuery('#pager'),
                rowNum: 2,

                rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
                sortname: 'id',
                sortorder: "desc",
                viewrecords: true,
                width: 960,
                height: 200,
                loadOnce: false,
                excelexport: true,
                imgpath: '/scripts/themes/coffee/images',
                caption: 'Stock Information'

            });
```

Please help me.

Comment: Any error in the console?

Comment: `loadOnce: false,` should be `true` and i suspect `cache/async` can't be used like this in jqGrid.

Comment: @JeremyThille This error is showing when i am debuggin " Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."

Comment: @Jai I have update the code but not working at all..

Comment: Add loadonce: true and remove cache, sync etc. Also add the below jsonReader property:
jsonReader: {
            root: "rows",
            page: "page",
            total: "total",
            records: "records",
            repeatitems: false,
            cell: "cell",
            id: "id"
        }

Comment: Yes did but not working @user3263194